# set the type of data in the zipped file that is permitted

Tags: python, csv, flask, zip

hello i'm a student and have a question, i want to set the data type inside zip file for more restriction.

i already done something like this :

```
upload_folder = 'static/upload_file'
allowed_extensions = set(['zip'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['upload_folder'] = upload_folder

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower() in allowed_extensions

@app.route('/uploader', methods=['POST','GET'])
def uploader():

    if 'POST' == request.method:
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        berkas = request.files['file']

        if berkas.filename == '':
            flash('no selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)

        if berkas and allowed_file(berkas.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(berkas.filename)
            berkas.save(os.path.join(app.config['upload_folder'], filename))

            directory_berkas = 'static/upload_file/'berkas.filename

            with ZipFile(direktori_berkas, 'r') as file:
                files = {name: file.read(name) for name in file.namelist()}
                list_data = file.namelist()
                file.close()

            list_data = [x for x in list_data if "__MACOSX" not in x]
            flash("upload success")

        return redirect(url_for('uploader',
                                 filename=filename,
                                 list_data=list_data))
```

how to set allowed extensions of the data type inside zip file just for csv ? thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple filter you could use is [str.endswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith). For example:

```py
list_data = [x for x in list_data if x.endswith(".csv") and "__MACOSX" not in x]
```

Comment: wah its simple and working, thankyou for the teaching sir, i already upvote it buy my rep still low and the publicly didnt change, im sorry sir

Comment: Happy to help! You should be able to accept the answer if you'd like